# getting error /usr/bin/env: sh: No such file or directory when running command play

Tags: shell, sh

I am a beginner on Play framework . I just extract Play framework files and extracted them and gave the path of play directory in `$PATH` global variable. After this when I run the the command on ubuntu play help, its giving me below error:

```
/usr/bin/env: sh: No such file or directory
```

Any clue why I am facing this error and how to resolve it ?

Comment: [Why is #!/usr/bin/env bash not working on my system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257969/56041)

Comment: that happened to me after moving the project to other computer, try to recreate manifest again

Answer (score 120):

This error usually happens if the script has windows line endings instead of unix line endings.

Try running **dos2unix** on the script and try running your command again to see if you get the same error.

```
dos2unix [filename]
```

Comment: This is the solution. I copied over the file from a windows machine. Installing and running dos2unix on the file enabled it to run without issues.

Comment: If on macOS, you won't have dos2unix by default but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23831111/31629 for a solution.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem, and resolved it using Notepad++, by clicking
Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix and then save the file.

Answer (score 5):

For peoples in Windows using Visual Studio Git module, if you encounter this error

[image]

You should setup `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` for `Path` in Environment Variables System

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, however my git\bin resides in another folder. use cmd to find your path using: c:>where git

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me, I had the same issue on Windows with GitHub Desktop.

Answer (score 5):

To resolve `env: sh\r: No such file or directory` issue:

Sometimes when files are transferred between different operating systems, the line endings can get converted to the wrong format, which can cause issues with shell scripts. Running dos2unix on the affected files is a quick and easy way to fix the line ending format and ensure that shell scripts can be executed without errors.

In my case, it was a transfer from Windows to MacOS.

This helped me:

1. Install `brew install dos2unix`
2. Convert all `.sh` files in repo: `find . -type f -name '*.sh' -exec dos2unix {} \;`
3. Conver all your hooks. I have one hook so I run only one command: `dos2unix .husky/pre-commit`

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to say thanks here, but this was perfect for me so thank you for being so helpful with your `commands` / suggestions

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux.
First I tried removing the Windows Lineendings by entering `tr -d '\r' < input.sh > output.sh`.
This did not help.
In fact the path actually did not exist instead of `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, I needed to use `#!/usr/bin/bash` in the first line of my script.

Answer (score 2):

`$PATH` environment variable is set in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`.

`source` the relevant configuration file or start a new bash terminal should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the sh terminal to bash 
using this [link](http://linuxwave.blogspot.in/2009/03/changing-default-shell-in-ubuntu.html) and everything should be fine.

```
1. Change user entry in /etc/passwd
a) edit /etc/passwd using any editor

$ vi /etc/passwd
b) find the line that belongs to the user (foo) that we about to modify
foo:x:1001:1001::/home/foo:/bin/sh
c) change from /bin/sh to /bin/bash
foo:x:1001:1001::/home/foo:/bin/bash
d) save
e) Logout and login back

2. Use chsh command
a) type chsh
$ chsh
b) You will be asked for password. Enter your password
c) This screen will appear
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
Login Shell [/bin/sh]:
d) Put /bin/bash at the menu and press Enter
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if your file is UTF-8 encoded with a "BOM" header (byte-order-mark) at the beginning of the file. Use your editor to "remove bom".

Answer (score 0):

Got this error when running on new Macbook Pro, because the default shell is now ZSH instead of Bash. Just type `bash` to enter bash shell, and run your script as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar error while using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2).

Setting git autocrlf to false via `git config --global core.autocrlf false`, and re-cloning the repository did the trick for me.

I've also [seen](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1725#issuecomment-824054644) folks recommend preventing WSL from adding Windows paths to PATH env var ([read more](https://gist.github.com/ilbunilcho/4280bd55a10cefef75e74986b6bff936)).

Answer (score -1):

i was getting slimier error in react-native because i forgot to add environment variable for android studio

add in .bashrc

```
 export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: You should not need to `export` anything more than once, and `PATH` will already have been `export`ed by your shell.

Comment: i was using react-native and the official doc say that https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup