# Google Dataproc initialization script error File not Found

Tags: shell, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using Google Dataproc to initialize a Jupyter cluster.
At first I used the "dataproc-initialization-actions" available in github, and it works like a charm.

This is the create cluster Call available in the documentation:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create my-dataproc-cluster \
    --metadata "JUPYTER_PORT=8124" \
    --initialization-actions \
        gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh \
    --bucket my-dataproc-bucket \
    --num-workers 2 \
    --properties spark:spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED=0,spark:spark.yarn.am.memory=1024m \
    --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
    --master-machine-type=n1-standard-4
```

But I want to customize it, so I got the initialization file and saved it o my Google Storage (that is under the same project where I'm trying to create the cluster). So, I changed the call to point to my script instead, like this:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create my-dataproc-cluster \
    --metadata "JUPYTER_PORT=8124" \
    --initialization-actions \
        gs://myjupyterbucketname/jupyter.sh \
    --bucket my-dataproc-bucket \
    --num-workers 2 \
    --properties spark:spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED=0,spark:spark.yarn.am.memory=1024m \
    --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
    --master-machine-type=n1-standard-4
```

But running this I got the following error:

```
Waiting on operation [projects/myprojectname/regions/global/operations/cf20
466c-ccb1-4c0c-aae6-fac0b99c9a35].
Waiting for cluster creation operation...done.
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) Operation [projects/myprojectname/
regions/global/operations/cf20466c-ccb1-4c0c-aae6-fac0b99c9a35] failed: Multiple
 Errors:
 - Google Cloud Dataproc Agent reports failure. If logs are available, they can
be found in 'gs://myjupyterbucketname/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/231e5160-75f3-
487c-9cc3-06a5918b77f5/my-dataproc-cluster-m'.
 - Google Cloud Dataproc Agent reports failure. If logs are available, they can
be found in 'gs://myjupyterbucketname/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/231e5160-75f3-
487c-9cc3-06a5918b77f5/my-dataproc-cluster-w-1'..
```

Well the files where there, so I think it may not be some access permission problem. The file named "dataproc-initialization-script-0_output" has the following content:

```
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This could be because the initialization script is in a Cloud Storage bucket which the project running the cluster is not able to access.

Could you try running "gcloud dataproc clusters diagnose my-dataproc-cluster" and share the resulting tarball with dataproc-feedback@google.com

Comment: will do it, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172405/getting-error-usr-bin-env-sh-no-such-file-or-directory-when-running-command-p)

Turns out the script had windows line endings instead of unix line endings.

Made an online convertion using [dos2unix](http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/dos2unix.tr) and now it runs fine.

With help from [@tix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4988140/tix) I could check that the file was reacheable using a SSH connection to the cluster (Successful `"gsutil cat gs://myjupyterbucketname/jupyter.sh"`)

AND, the initialization file was correctly saved locally in the directory `"/etc/google-dataproc/startup-scripts/dataproc-initialization-script-0"`

Comment: I really think that Google should address this issue and do not produce such misleading error message :(