# Delete all "\n" occurrences with sed

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

I would like to delete all `"\n"` (quotes, new line, quotes) in a text file.

I have tried:
`sed 's/"\n"//g' < in > out`
and also `sed '/"\n"/d' < in > out` but non of those seds worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Comment: you probably want unix2dos, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6373961/297323

Comment: Do you mean " at the end of a line, a literal newline and a " on the beginning of the next line, or do you mean those four characters literally?

Comment: To clarify, since the representation of what should be replaced is confusing: based on what answer was accepted, the intent is to remove all 3-character substrings composed of: a literal double quote, followed by an actual newline, followed by a literal double quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with GNU sed on Linux: I don't have a Mac to test with.

```
sed  '
    # this reads the whole file into pattern space
    :a; N; $ bb; ba; :b
    # *now* make the replacement
    s/"\n"//g
' <<END
one
two"
"three
four"
five
"six
END
```

```
one
twothree
four"
five
"six
```

This perl command accomplishes the same thing:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/"\n"//g'
```

Comment: For those unfamiliar with Perl: `perl -0777` is an idiom for reading an input file _as a whole_ (all lines at once).

Comment: + for the Perl solution, and the _principle_ of the `sed` solution, which, however, as noted, _doesn't_ work on OSX; for a variant that _does_ work on OSX, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29404564/45375).

Answer (score 0):

Try this -- you need to escape the backslash to make it literal.

```
sed 's/"\\n"//g' < in > out
```

Verified on OSX.

Comment: sed is line oriented by default, so unless you're using N or H, there will be no newlines in the pattern/hold space

Answer (score 0):

This awk-oneliner works here, you can give it a try:

```
 awk -F'"\n"' -v RS='\0' -v ORS="" '{$1=$1;print}' file
```

a small test: tested with gawk

```
kent$  cat f
foo"
"bar"
"bla"
new line should be kept
this too

kent$  awk -F'"\n"' -v RS='\0' -v ORS="" '{$1=$1;print}' f
foo bar bla"
new line should be kept
this too
```

If you don't want to have the space between `foo` and `bar` `blah` .., add `-v OFS=""` to awk

Comment: That also changed `foo"\nbar` to `foo"bar`

Comment: @user3840048 no it won't, at least here it won't. ;) did you test with gawk?

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29389177/45375) was marked as such because of the *Perl* command it contains.

The `sed` command doesn't actually work on OSX, because it uses features specific to *GNU* `sed`, whereas OSX use *BSD* `sed`.

An *equivalent* answer requires only a few tweaks - note that this will work with *both* BSD *and* GNU `sed`:

Using **multiple `-e` options**:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}; s/"\n"//g' < in > out
```

Or, using an **[ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)** in Bash:

```
sed $':a\n$!{N;ba\n}; s/"\\n"//g' < in > out
```

Or, using a ***multi-line* string literal**:

```
sed ':a
  $!{N;ba
  }; s/"\n"//g' < in > out
```

BSD `sed`  requires labels (e.g., `:a`) and branching commands (e.g., `b`) to be terminated with an *actual newline* (whereas in *GNU* `sed` a `;` suffices), or, alternatively, for the script to be broken into multiple `-e` options, with each part ending where a newline is required.
For a detailed discussion of the differences between GNU and BSD `sed`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375

`$':a\n$!{N;ba\n}'` is a common `sed` idiom for reading *all* input lines into the so-called pattern space (buffer on which (subsequent) commands operate):

- `:a` is a label that can be branched to
- `$!` matches every line *but* the last

  - `{N;ba\n}` keeps building the buffer by adding the current line (`N`) to it, then branching back to label `:a` to repeat the cycle.
- Once the *last* line is reached, no branching is performed, and the buffer at that point contains *all* input lines, at which point the desired substitution (`s/"\n"//g`) is performed on the entire buffer.

---

As for **why the OP's approach didn't work**:

`sed` reads files *line by line* by default, so by default it can only operate on *one line at a time*.

In order to be able to replace *newline* chars. - i.e., to operate *across multiple lines* - you must *explicitly read multiple/all lines* first, as above.

Answer (score -1):

instead of sed you could also use tr, I've tested it and for me it worked

```
tr -d '"\\n"' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: That removes all quotes in the file

Comment: all new lines are only removed if you forget to escape the backslash

Comment: If you escape the backslash, then `tr` will additionally remove all `\ ` and `n` characters. The OP's problem can't be solved with `tr`, which operates on (sets of) _individual_ characters only.