# Flask virtual environment: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I'm working on a little side project and it's my first time using Flask. 
I'm working with a virtual environment and therefore I have a shebang at the beginning of my script, that looks like this

```
#!flask/bin/python
```

When I try to execute my script from the command line, I get the following error:

```
-bash: ./run.py: flask/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I know that this means that the python interpreter couldn't be found, but if I navigate into flask/bin i can see the interpreter inside. Those are all the files inside of flask/bin

> activate
>   activate.csh
>   activate.fish
>   activate_this.py
>   easy_install
>   easy_install-2.7
>   pip
>   pip2
>   pip2.7
>   python
>   python-config
>   python2 -> python
>   python2.7 -> python
>   wheel

I tried to delete my virtual environment directory and create it again, but this didn't help.

Why does my shebang not work in this case?

Comment: Do you have an actual carriage return in the script you're trying to run?

Comment: Please show the actual run.py file.

Comment: Also see [shebang line not working with cr-lf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108588/shebang-line-not-working-with-cr-lf) at the unix SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write the script in a Windows environment and then move it over to a UNIX environment? Because the line endings are different, files written in one environment will not automatically work on the other. See [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html) for more info.

To resolve this, try using dos2unix, or if you're using something like Notepad++ on Windows, there are often options to save the file in a Windows format.

Comment: Thank you! That helped. I found the command line solution with perl [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373888/converting-newline-formatting-from-mac-to-windows), since the sed solution didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> -bash: ./run.py: flask/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
> ```

Bash ignores the shebang line (it's a comment to bash). The shebang line is instead handled by the Unix program loader. If the first two characters of an executable file are `#!`, the program loader

- Scans ahead for a new line character, up to a system-specific limit. With Linux, this limit is 127 characters.
- Truncates trailing whitespace from the end of the line. The Linux kernel code to do this is lines 46 to 56 of [binfmt_script.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5924bbecd0267d87c24110cbe2041b5075173a25/fs/binfmt_script.c). A carriage return is not whitespace in this context.
- Looks for the name of the interpreter, starting with the first non-whitespace character after the leading `#!`.
- Tries to execute the named interpreter with the script name as an argument.

In short, the program loader is looking for a file named `python^M` rather than `python` in `flask/bin`. That file does not exist.

The immediate solution is to run `dos2unix` against your script. The longer term solution is not to use Windows tools to create files targeted for a Unix machine.

Answer (score -1):

flask/bin/python^M, is it because your file was written in windows, and executed in unix?