# How to avoid this error No such file or directory when run maven

Tags: java, maven

I have Backend codes and APIs in a folder I download it from mail. I am using Mac OS.

But when I run `./mvnw` in terminal I got the error

`-bash: ./mvnw: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Shouldn't be /bin/bash?. Seems you don't have such shell. Also you are using Windows generated/modified file (^M is "newline" on windows) on linux. Try to get rid of it from script (if you are possitive that you have such shell)

Comment: are you running this command from the directory where pom.xml lies?

Comment: yes I am running from that directory @JaiDixit

Comment: `^M`= Ctrl-M = ASCII 13 (M being the 13th letter) = CR, `\r`. Where CR+LF, `\r\n` is the Windows line ending as opposed to `\n` for MacOSX, Linux and more. You might edit mvnw and remove then `\r`s.

Comment: I got it, changed to MacOSx @JoopEggen,@Antoniossss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your bash gets confused by DOS line endings. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373888/converting-newline-formatting-from-mac-to-windows) goes into some detail on how to handle those on MacOS

Comment: The way you can tell this is by the ^M at the end.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error as you, installing mvn wrapper in the following way worked for me.

```
mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper
```

Then cd to the folder where pom.xml file is, and then re-run the ./mvnw command

Answer (score 1):

I tried `dos2unix filename` it works. For using this command we have to install dos2unix

This is the link for install

[https://symwisedownload.symantec.com//resources/sites/SYMWISE/content/live/SOLUTIONS/228000/TECH228385/en_US/dos2unix-5.3.3-0.pkg?**gda**=1539204692_786de4ebe956ae8f24de673f5398dd64](https://symwisedownload.symantec.com//resources/sites/SYMWISE/content/live/SOLUTIONS/228000/TECH228385/en_US/dos2unix-5.3.3-0.pkg?__gda__=1539204692_786de4ebe956ae8f24de673f5398dd64)

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the mvnw file is not there. Go to your maven project which you need to build and then run mvnw like bellow by pointing to the path of mvnw.

sh /home/user/maven-wrapper-master/mvnw clean install

Or else copy the mvnw file into the maven project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, so in this situation ./mvnw doesn`t work, but I tried to write the absolute path to the mvnw file and it works! So try it!