# Usage of Line feed and Carriage return

Tags: java, windows, carriage-return, linefeed

`System.out.println("Hello \rWorld");` 
**Output:- world**

> why is the Hello missing, I am using Windows. How does /r,/n,/r/n differ ?

Answer (score 0):

\r is carriage return (CR)
\n is Line feed (LF)

\r\n is a carriage return with the newline char
Windows, and DOS before it, uses a pair of CR and LF characters to terminate lines

\n
UNIX (Including Linux and FreeBSD) uses an LF character only

OSX also uses a single LF character( 0x0A ), but the classic Mac operating system used a single CR character for line breaks( 0x0D ).

You can read more at 
[Link](https://hackjutsu.com/2015/12/07/Line%20Breaks%20in%20Win-OSX-Linux/)
and from a previously asked 
[StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373888/converting-newline-formatting-from-mac-to-windows)