# Rbuildignore not ignoring .git

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, r-package

I'm updating a package that is currently on CRAN.  Running `devtools::check()` locally consistently gives the WARNING

```
> checking package subdirectories ... WARNING
  Found the following directory with the name of a version control directory:
  These should not be in a package tarball.
    ./.git
```

and NOTE

```
> checking for hidden files and directories ... NOTE
  Found the following hidden files and directories:
    .git
  These were most likely included in error. See section 'Package
  structure' in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.
  
  CRAN-pack does not know about
    .git
```

When I check on winbuilder, I no longer get the WARNING, but I do get the NOTE.

This is my .Rbuildignore file, which *should* be ignoring the .git folder, but isn't for some reason (?)

```
^.*\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
^cran-comments\.md$
^\.Rhistory$
^docs$
^\.travis\.yml$
^CRAN-RELEASE$
^\.git$
^\.github$
```

I recently migrated from Windows to Mac (os 12.1), and I'm running R version 4.1.1 and RStudio version 1.4.1717.  Thanks for any help - I can't figure this one out, and it's making me crazy.

---

EDIT:  For reproducibility, my package is currently on Github at https://github.com/mbtyers/riverdist

Comment: Stab in the dark, but have you converted the line endings in your `.Rbuildignore` from Windows to Mac line endings?

Comment: @Hobo This sounds promising - what are Mac line endings?

Comment: What happens if you just ignore with `.git`? It seems to work on my build ignores.

Comment: @NelsonGon My Buildignore includes `^\.git$`, is that what you meant?

Comment: I meant change the regex to just `.git` and `.github`. This would ignore the entire dir?

Comment: @NelsonGon No luck with `.git`, `^\.git`, `^git`, or `^git$`.  `^\git$` throws an error when I Install & Restart, which is encouraging since it was starting to think my buildignore was being ignored entirely!

Comment: @MattTyers - sorry, I went to bed after posting that, and haven't looked until now. I don't have a Mac to test, but Windows uses two characters (`\r\n`) to signify the end of a line.  Mac, being unix-based, just uses `\n`.  Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6373888 for details, including conversion.  The easiest way will be to use the `dos2unix` command-line utility, if you have it or can install it.  This question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3569997 might help too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one had a strange and unrelated solution, which I will post in case someone else runs into a similar issue.  I should have seen the clue when I ran "build source package" (or`devtools::build()` or `devtools::check()`) and in the long scrolling output would get a long series of

```
rm: /var/folders/1r/qj42pgb ... 3c4f: Operation not permitted
rm: /var/folders/1r/qj42pgb ... b6ad: Operation not permitted
rm: /var/folders/1r/qj42pgb ... s/e3: Directory not empty
rm: /var/folders/1r/qj42pgb ... c5d0: Operation not permitted
```

My guess is that when I transferred my work from a Windows machine to a Mac via external drive, some directory was corrupted or there was a permissions issue.  If so, I could imagine my machine being unable to follow my .Rbuildignore, or exclude version control directories as mentioned in @user2554330's answer.

Ultimately, I downloaded a fresh version from Github (which I had been pushing to) and built/checked on that, and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 2):

Edited to simplify:

You can leave `.git` out of `.Rbuildignore` completely:  version control directories are automatically ignored for several version control systems, including `git`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - unfortunately, neither suggestion (removing the `.git` line completely or turning it into `^\.git`) made the WARNING or NOTE go away.  Trying winbuilder, I still have the NOTE.

Comment: Is your package on Github?  We can't reproduce the issue with what you've posted.

Comment: Also:  you haven't told us how you built the tarball.  Do you get the problem if you build it from the command line using `R CMD build`?

Comment: Good suggestion with the Github link - see edit above.  So far I've built the tarball using the "Install & Restart" button in RStudio.

Comment: I think the problem may be that "Install & Restart" *doesn't* build a tarball, it just installs locally.  You've probably been submitting an unmodified tarball after each attempted change.  To get RStudio to build a tarball, use "Build Source Package" in the "Build | More..." menu.

Comment: When I do "Build Source Package" on a checked out copy of your repos, I don't get any .git files in the tarball.

Comment: Found a solution (below).  Thanks again for your help - I learned some new things from your answer & comments, even if it turned out to be something else!